# Is there a way to remove time from result in python when executing the code?

Tags: python, time

I am trying to get the difference in between two dates using Python. But every time I run my code I get time mentioned in my result that is [00:00:00]. How do we remove and just display number of days.

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.today().date()

print(now)

userinput = input('Enter your deadline of the project(mm/dd/yyyy)')

projectdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(userinput,'%m/%d/%Y').date()

print(projectdate)

daysleft = projectdate - now

result = (projectdate - now).days//7

print('The number of days left in your project are....' +' '+ str(daysleft) + ' '+ 'days' + ' ' + 'or' + ' ' + str(result) +' ' + 'weeks')
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
str(daysleft)
```

to

```
str(daysleft.days)
```

Answer (score 0):

For your use case (you only care about time entities bigger than an hour) - you might want to use `datetime.date` rather than `datetime.datetime`.

Datetime module has special class called `datetime.timedelta` that represents a time interval and can be easily converted. E.g.

```
start = datetime.date(year=2019, month=3, day=1)
finish = datetime.date(year=2019, month=5, day=1)

print("There are " + str((finish - start).days) + " days between start and finish")
```

Comment: Wrt _"you might want to use `datetime.date` rather than `datetime.date`"_ - Did you mean to say "you might want to use `datetime.date` rather than `datetime.datetime`"?

Answer (score 0):

You can also make slight modification to the print statement

```
print('The number of days left in your project are....' +' '+ str(daysleft.days) + ' '+ 'days' + ' ' + 'or' + ' ' + str(result) +' ' + 'weeks')
```

Comment: @AbidRaza, you are welcome. You can also accept it as an answer, if it solves your problem.